# Is it possible to override resource file from Android's Library Module?

Tags: android, android-library

I have two Android Libraries: A and B. B has an `EditText` that receives a custom `attr` `app:theme`which is a XML file from `raw`res directory. A supplies B with this file. I have an app C that uses A. Is it possible from C override the file present in `raw` res dir from A which will be latter passed to B?

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should be possible with simple parameter passing. For example if you create instance of object that's defined in library C (which have inside lib A and A contains B... ), then you can create parameterized constructors with your XML file that goes down to library B.

I don't know the specifics. But event without more details I think it's possible.

Comment: Due to the libraries B nature it wouldn't be possible. App C launches an Activity from lib A. On this activity's XML layout I pass the res XML file to lib B. I think I could override this passing if I was creating libs B EditText programmatically, however, I was attempting to avoid that because this approach can become messy when you are using InputTextLayout